# How can I handle duplicate fields name in embeded struct in GO?

Tags: go

I have a struct type wants to include all fields from a few other structs. Like below code:

```
type Record struct {
    events.APIGatewayProxyRequest          `json:",omitempty"`
    events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest `json:",omitempty"`
    events.DynamoDBEvent                   `json:",omitempty"`
    events.SQSEvent                        `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

The sub struct are all from AWS sdk-go library. The problem I have is that the `go` complains about the duplicate field exists in more than one sub struct like:

```
structtag: struct field Resource repeats json tag "resource" also at apigw.go:7
```

how can I handle this situation?

Comment: How would you like it to be handled? There is only one json key `"resource"` and 4 struct fields mapped to it. How would you like to be handled in the case of unmarshaling and how in the case of marshaling?

Comment: The `resource` under each sub-struct are same which is a common type declared by aws-sdk. I'd like to see error only if the duplicate name has different type.

Comment: So are you interested in marshaling or unmarshaling? And what should happen if you marshal this struct where each embedded struct has a different value for `Resource`?

Answer (score -2):

To resolve the issue of duplicate field names in embedded structs, give the embedded fields unique field names in the parent struct using field tags. Example:

```
type Record struct {
    APIGatewayProxyRequest events.APIGatewayProxyRequest `json:"apiGatewayRequest,omitempty"`
    DynamoDBEvent events.DynamoDBEvent `json:"dynamoDBEvent,omitempty"`
    SQSEvent events.SQSEvent `json:"sqsEvent,omitempty"`
    APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest `json:"apiGatewayWebsocketRequest,omitempty"`
}
```